# Oracle PL/SQL : remove "space characters" from a string

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

In my Oracle 10g database I would like to remove "space characters" (spaces, tabs, carriage returns...) from the values of a table field.

Is `TRANSLATE()` the way to go ? For example something like:

```
MY_VALUE := TRANSLATE(MY_VALUE,
  CHR(9) || CHR(10) || CHR(11) || CHR(12) || CHR(13) || ' ', '');
```

Or is there any better alternative (something like `[:space:]` in PHP PCRE) ?

Thanks for any piece of advice.

Comment: By the way, your `TRANSLATE` won't work because you have NULL as the third parameter. You could use `TRANSLATE(my_value,'A'||CHR(9)||CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||'','A')`

Comment: You're right, thanks! Oh I love Oracle... :-p

Comment: Remove any whitespaces in Oracle PL/SQL and Forms

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'd go for regexp_replace, although I'm not 100% sure this is usable in PL/SQL

```
my_value := regexp_replace(my_value, '[[:space:]]*','');
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow at work, and will keep you informed. Thanks already for pointing `REGEXP_REPLACE` (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm). Seems that's what I need since it claims to be "POSIX" compatible so `[[:space:]]` should be recognized.

Answer (score 22):

Shorter version of:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( my_value, '[[:space:]]', '' )
```

Would be:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( my_value, '\s')
```

Neither of the above statements will remove "null" characters.

To remove "nulls" encase the statement with a replace

Like so:

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE( my_value, '\s'), CHR(0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the NULL removal explanation.  Really needed this for something.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're comfortable with regular expressions, you probably want to use the REGEXP_REPLACE function.   If you want to eliminate anything that matches the [:space:] POSIX class

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( my_value, '[[:space:]]', '' )


SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select '|' ||
  2         regexp_replace( 'foo ' || chr(9), '[[:space:]]', '' ) ||
  3         '|'
  4*   from dual
SQL> /

'|'||
-----
|foo|
```

If you want to leave one space in place for every set of continuous space characters, just add the `+` to the regular expression and use a space as the replacement character.

```
with x as (
  select 'abc 123  234     5' str
    from dual
)
select regexp_replace( str, '[[:space:]]+', ' ' )
  from x
```

Comment: Could this regex be improved to also remove a leading space? I had to wrap this in a trim to accommodate the leading.

Answer (score 4):

```
select regexp_replace('This is a test   ' || chr(9) || ' foo ', '[[:space:]]', '') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE
--------------
Thisisatestfoo
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace one or more white space characters by a single blank you should use `{2,}` instead of `*`, otherwise you would `insert` a blank between all non-blank characters.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( my_value, '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' ' )
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove any whitespaces you could use:

```
myValue := replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(myValue, chr(32)), chr(9)),  chr(10)), chr(11)), chr(12)), chr(13));
```

Example: remove all whitespaces in a table:

```
update myTable t
    set t.myValue = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(t.myValue, chr(32)), chr(9)), chr(10)), chr(11)), chr(12)), chr(13))
where
    length(t.myValue) > length(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(t.myValue, chr(32)), chr(9)), chr(10)), chr(11)), chr(12)), chr(13)));
```

or

```
update myTable t
    set t.myValue = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(t.myValue, chr(32)), chr(9)), chr(10)), chr(11)), chr(12)), chr(13))
where
    t.myValue like '% %'
```

Comment: Is this more performant or otherwise better than the regular expression based solutions already proposed here?