# Extra spaces after loading from a text file with SQL*Loader

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I'm using Oracle 11g, and I'm trying to load data from a text file with SQL*Loader

Here is a sample of the data (there are much more columns):

```
123456789876543212,100,333,432,02/05/2014,02/05/2014,02/05/2014,1.1,AA
```

I want to load the data into the DB first as a VARCHAR2, and then to convert them to the correct datatype in the DB, with a query. It's much more easy in my opinion.

Here is my table (`MyTable`):

```
create table MyTable
(
   A varchar2(500)
   B varchar2(500)
   C varchar2(500)
   D varchar2(500)
   E varchar2(500)
   F varchar2(500)
   G varchar2(500)
   H varchar2(500)
   I varchar2(500)
)
```

Here is my loading script:

```
load data
infile 'D:\MyFile.txt'
into table MyTable
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(
       A char(4000),
       B char(4000),
       C char(4000),
       D char(4000),
       E char(4000),
       F char(4000),
       G char(4000),
       H char(4000),
       I char(4000)
)
```

Here is how the data looks like after being loaded into the DB.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2,1 0 0,3 3 3,4 3 2,0 2 / 0 5 / 2 0 1 4,0 2 / 0 5 / 2 0 1 4,0 2 / 0 5 / 2 0 1 4, 1 . 1,A A
```

Why does my data look like this? What are these spaces? I don't have a lot of experience with data loading.

I'm guessing that the problem is the data types of the table in the DB and in the loading file. What is the right way to defined such as data? I want to load the data as is into the DB. I'll make the conversation in the DB with a query. Please note that the first column has 18 digits.

Comment: If you cant remove from file you can refer to make replace of the string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505835/oracle-pl-sql-remove-space-characters-from-a-string

Comment: It depends massively on your text editor @Omri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal reason for "spaces" being inserted between every character after loading is because there is a [nul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (ASCII 0) after every character in your original text file. If you look at your file in a text editor in Hexadecimal you should be able to see this (it'll be represented as 00). You can also look at your table using the [`DUMP()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm#SQLRF00635) function.

Without extra parameters, `DUMP()` is a useful function that returns the [data-type code](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG) of the data you pass it, the length of the data in bytes and the internal representation of ''expr''. There are a few other options which are explained in the documentation.

From the below you'll see that the data-type code is 96, which represents a CHAR., the length is 1 i.e. the string is 1 byte long and the internal representation is 97, which is the ASCII code for `a`.

```
SQL> select dump('a')
  2    from dual;

DUMP('A')
----------------
Typ=96 Len=1: 97
```

In your case you're expecting a code of 0 for nuls.

I'd go back to your supplier and tell them to remove the characters, after you've double checked, as you won't be able to tell whether they're actual nul characters or part of a multi-byte character. I've [previously written about the strategies for removing nuls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202050/how-to-get-rid-of-nul-characters-in-oracle-database/24206332#24206332) from the database should you be unable to get the file fixed.